# How to use peek and pop on views without using 'indexPathForItemAtPoint'?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface

I'm pretty new to iOS coding and swift (3).

I currently have a classic view controller with a stack view and 3 buttons in this stack view:

[image: Storyboard]

I'm trying to integrate peek and pop on my buttons.

```
func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController?
```

The problem is that, in all examples and documentions I read the controller is either a TableViewController or either CollectionViewController, so people use the following method :

```
func indexPathForItem(at point: CGPoint) -> IndexPath?
```

and then, can retrieve the element targeted by the user.

But I use a classic StackView, so I tried to use CGPoint given by the delegate to guess the targeted button in the stack view, but the 'frame' property of the button return its location relative to the stack view and not the main frame.

Why I'm using stack view ? Because I change the stack view axis when the user rotate the device, so buttons are next to each others.

I'm pretty sure I'm implementation is bad too so I someone have suggestions, I will be happy about it.